# CakePHP 2.6, Redis session/cache being destroyed on redirect

Tags: php, session, cakephp, caching, redis

I'm in the process of upgrading our project from Centos-6/Apache 2.0/PHP5.3/Cake 2.0/File Cache (6/3/2/0/F) to Centos-7/Apache 2.4/PHP5.6/Cake 2.6/Redis Cache & Session (7/6/4/6/R).

The upgrade works great and as intended if I leave the  7/6/4/6/R with File Caching and php sessions.  But I've installed Redis following a few tutorials and everything works as intended from PHP 5.6 recognizing Redis, CakePHP gets 18 for 18 tests passes in test.php, yet the Redis Sessions are being destroyed on Redirects.

**Core.php**

```
//Replaces standard
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'cache',
'timeout' => '100',
'start' => true,
'checkAgent' => false,
'handler' => array(
'config' => 'session'
)
));
//Engine
$engine = 'Redis';

//Bottom of Core
 Cache::config ('session', array (
'Engine' => $engine,
'Prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_session_',
'Duration' => $duration
));
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'Redis'));
```

**AppController.php**

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'view'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction'=>array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
            )
        )
    ));
```

**UsersController.php** -  Login Function - C&P'd from Blog example

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        //print_r($_SESSION);die();
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
}
```

Will print the intended and entire Session Array key=>values.  PERFECT!!! Now If I let the redirect through.

**CompaniesController.php**

```
public function view($id = null) {
        print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

Contains no key=>values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two extra item to check.  After these were modified Redis worked perfectly with Cake 2.6.4.

1) Re-verify your phpinfo() and make sure there is no local session variables blocking the Global php.ini settings.  Mine were coming from httpd's php.conf.

2) session_start() does need to be added, even though CakePHP Documentation states you don't have to use this command if the loaded component of Session or Auth is used.  i placed the command on line one of webroot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_write_close before redirect as internally session_write_close called on __destroy.

But this event happens after you have sent "Location: " header.

Try this in AppController:

```
public function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
    if ($exit && $this->Components->enabled('Session') && $this->Session->started()) {
        session_write_close();
    }
    return parent::redirect($url, $status, $exit);
}
```

Same problem still in Cake3. In symfony2 it's fixed — before redirect session component closes itself.